# CAN0 confustion in Datasheet for ATSAMC21G uC

Tags: microcontroller, can

I currently narrowing my search for a uC with a CAN controller and a few ADC inputs. One of them is the '*ATSAMC21G*' 32bit uC from Microchip.

In the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/SAM-C20C21-Family-Datasheet-DS60001479C.pdf) on p.31 is the table of the pin configuration.  My question: Why are there 4 entries for CAN0 (CAN0/TX->pin33, CAN0/RX->pin34 and CAN0/TX->pin37, CAN0/RX->pin38)? Can I choose between the four pins OR is one pair for receiving and the other for transmitting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose pin33 or pin37 as TX line and choose pin34 or pin38 as RX line.
If you look at page 675 (34.4 Signal Description), it says `Refer to for details on the pin mapping for this peripheral. One signal can be mapped to one of several pins.` You'll need to configure the correct pins by setting some bits in the registers. But a quick look at the "Related Links", shows that they explain it well in the datasheet.

Comment: thank you. I am reading so much datasheets its overwhelming.

Comment: @v3xX yeah they can be. Don't be put off by them, only read the sections you need. You can always read more if you need more features. For now, chapter 6, 28 and 34 looks like worth the read.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this part has 2 CAN peripherals as an option, so that could be why. Here's my working code for using pin 24 and 25. It is using the ASF register map (sam.h):

```
PORT->Group[0].PINCFG[PIN_PA24].reg = PORT_PINCFG_PMUXEN;
PORT->Group[0].PINCFG[PIN_PA25].reg = PORT_PINCFG_PMUXEN;

// set Pin MUX to magic number 6 = magic letter G = CAN Tx/Rx, see manual chp 6, I/O multiplexing
PORT->Group[0].PMUX[PIN_PA24/2].reg = PORT_PMUX_PMUXE(6) | 
                                      PORT_PMUX_PMUXO(6);
```